# assigning "Get" Request data to Text field

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, get

My get data response is like

I want "title" and "date" should be shown in my view controller "label values"

get method calls when app running and the data should display in either text fields "or" in label

My Code is

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else { fatalError() }

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }

    if let data = data {
        print(data)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
}.resume()
```

out put is :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
]
```

I want to print "username":
                   "email":
values in my Storyboard labels

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have obj-c code I am obj-c dev now I have to work on swift so

Comment: You should use the `completion` block. If you put your tried code here, we can help you with that.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: in this responce, you got multiple user info, So which user name you want to print? first one or second?

Comment: I need both result to be printed .I will use table view to display data to show dynamical increase users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result contains **multiple users**, so you should first iterate over them and find the user you want. Then you can set text on your UI elements in the **Main thread**.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else { fatalError() }

typealias User = [String: Any]

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }

    if let data = data {
        print(data)
        do {
            let usersJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [User]
            print(usersJson)

            // Since the result is an array of users
            for user in usersJson {
                guard let userName = user["username"] as? String else { return assertionFailure("Invalid username") }
                print(userName)

                // All UI works should done in main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    <#usernameLabel#>.text = username
                }
            }            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
}.resume()
```

I suggest you take a look at **Swift Codable**. It will boost your coding and minimize syntax and human errors.

Comment: Thank you Hosseini but how to take email ?

Comment: Did you know about ‘dictionary’? You can replace “username” with any key you need like: user[“email”]

Comment: I wrote Like this in button action and clicking the button twice only changing the label text I don't no why I want to change this by clicking once  let userName = user["emp_name"] as? String else { return assertionFailure("Invalid username") }
 print(userName)
                        guard let email = user["title"] as? String else {return assertionFailure("Invalid Email")}
                        print(email).     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.nameTxField.text = userName
                            self.passwordTxField.text = email
                        }